# Drill down aggregate report in J Meter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am having the following report from aggregate report from the J Meter.  So If I can interpret the report correctly then the 50% of transaction didn't take 0.5 sec (like 50% of the 1365 ~ 683 number of transaction). But if I want to  drill down more like how much number of transactions  or % of the transaction from the total are between 50-70% line , 70-90% line, 90-95% line and 95-99% line. How to achieve this like do I need a plugin or any additional script which I required (If I am not allowed to use any analytical/reporting tools like grafana)?

Currently I am using Apache JMeter 5.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) which can control the percentiles display in the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) along with their default values:

- `aggregate_rpt_pct1=90`
- `aggregate_rpt_pct2=95`
- `aggregate_rpt_pct3=99`

so you can change the properties values to whatever percentiles you want, to wit if you change them to 60, 70 and 80 - JMeter will show different metrics.

So if you run JMeter 2 times, first time default and second time providing the following command-line arguments:

```
jmeter -Jaggregate_rpt_pct1=60 -Jaggregate_rpt_pct2=70 -Jaggregate_rpt_pct3=80
```

and open the .jtl results file using Aggregate Report listener you will see different percentiles metrics:

[image]

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)